# show a message when user doesn't select a date from the calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am new to ASP.NET and C#,
What I want is to show a message to the user "Please select a date!" when the user doesn't select a date from the calendar!

I know that we use an If statement for it but, what should I put in the condition ?

here is my code

```
HTML:
    <asp:Calendar ID="Cal" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="But" runat="server" Text="show date" OnClick="but" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label7"  runat="server" Text="Your date will show here!" />
C#:
 protected void but(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Label7.Text = "here is your selected date" +  
               Cal.SelectedDate.Date.ToLongDateString();

         if (Cal.SelectedDate.Date == 0  )
            {

            }}
```

Thank you

Comment: You have not provided anywhere near enough information to help you. You should provide a sample of your code with enough to show what you have done. Also, show us what you have tried and what the results were and any error messages.

Comment: ok, done! sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

The SelectedDate property is a DateTime value. Thus, you must compare it to DateTime value.

According to the Microsoft docs. the default value for SelectedDate is DateTime.MinValue. Also, it might be a better idea to set your response after you verify a valid value.

So your method might look something like this:

```
protected void but(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Cal.SelectedDate != DateTime.MinValue)
    {
        Label7.Text = "here is your selected date" +  Cal.SelectedDate.ToLongDateString();
    }
    else
    {
        //Whatever you want to happen if no valid date


    }
}
```